# Using .net Selenium, hover and select from Nav Menu

Tags: .net, selenium, menuitem

Am facing trouble in selecting from Menu items using Selenium .net framework, the DOM contains `<ul>` `<li>`

Here is a Menu Structure, am trying to select Level2B from the below code

```
<div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_ctl00_RadMenu1Panel" style="display: block;">
   <div tabindex="0" id="ctl00_RadMenu1" class="RadMenu RadMenu_Bootstrap" style="visibility: visible; z-index: 8000;">
      <ul class="rmRootGroup rmRoundedCorners rmHorizontal">
         <li class="rmItem " style="z-index: 0;">
            <a class="rmLink rmRootLink" href="#"><span class="rmText rmExpandDown">Level0</span></a>
            <div class="rmSlide" style="visibility: visible; height: 74px; width: 190px; display: none; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 56px; z-index: 9;">
               <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel1" style="display: block; top: -74px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; transition: none 0s ease 0s;">
                  <li class="rmTopRight"></li>
                  <li class="rmBottomLeft"></li>
                  <li class="rmBottomRight"></li>
                  <li class="rmTopFix"></li>
                  <li class="rmBottomFix"></li>
                  <li class="rmItem rmFirst">
                     <a class="rmLink" href="Level1A.aspx" style="width: 190px;"><span class="rmText rmExpandRight">Level1A</span></a>
                     <div class="rmSlide">
                        <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel2">
                           <li class="rmItem rmFirst"><a class="rmLink" href="Level2A.aspx"><span class="rmText">Level2A</span></a></li>
                           <li class="rmItem "><a class="rmLink" href="Level2B.aspx"><span class="rmText">Level2B &amp; Level2B</span></a></li>
                           <li class="rmItem ">
                              <a class="rmLink" href="#"><span class="rmText">Level2D</span></a>
                              <div class="rmSlide">
                                 <ul class="rmVertical rmGroup rmLevel3">
                                    <li class="rmItem rmFirst"><a class="rmLink" href="Level3A.aspx"><span class="rmText">Level3A</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="rmItem "><a class="rmLink" href="Level3B.aspx?resultid=5"><span class="rmText">Level3B</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="rmItem rmLast"><a class="rmLink" href="Level3C.aspx?resultid=10"><span class="rmText">Level3C</span></a></li>
                                 </ul>
                              </div>
                           </li>
                           <li class="rmItem rmLast"><a class="rmLink" href="#"><span class="rmText">Level2F</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="rmItem rmLast"><a class="rmLink" href="Level1B.aspx" style="width: 190px;"><span class="rmText">Level1B</span></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code I have tried for, am getting element not found exception

```
var qmsMenu = t._driver.FindElement(By.ID("ctl00_RadMenu1"));
            var menuItemsAll = qmsMenu.FindElements(By.ClassName("rmItem "));
            var n=menuItemsAll.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (menuItemsAll[i].Text.ToLower().Contains("Level0"))
                    menuItemsAll[i].Click();

                var subMenuItems = menuItemsAll[i].FindElement(By.ClassName("rmSlide"));
                var leafNodes = subMenuItems.FindElements(By.ClassName("rmItem "));
                var leafNodesCount = leafNodes.Count;
                for (int j = 0; j < leafNodesCount; j++)
                {
                    if (leafNodes[j].Text.ToLower().Contains("Level2B"))
                        leafNodes[j].Click();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Code trials? Errors encountered?

Comment: @DebanjanB, updated the trials and exceptions.

Comment: I have updated as below, now am getting value in "MainMenu" like Level0, Level1, Level2,
 please help me in selecting Level0

`IWebElement MainMenu = t._driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class, 'rmRootGroup')]"));`